# Advanced reading on Anti-aliasing?

Tags: anti-aliasing

I know the basics of how anti-aliasing works, but i wanted to read more about the advanced techniques used to get better looking and more performant AA. Where can i go to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Steve Gibson has an excellent set of articles on sub-pixel font smoothing: http://www.grc.com/ctwhat.htm